# Send emails without user interaction

Tags: android, email

What is the best way to send emails without using intents?

I was using android GMailSender, and it worked great just until recentily. It still works for android 4.0 and bellow, but gives a SSL error on version 4.2.

The error:

> Got javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.exception.ExtCertPathValidatorException:
>   Could not validate certificate: current time: Sat Jan 01 03:20:30 EET
>   2000, validation time: Thu Jun 21 03:00:00 EEST 2012 while executing
>   fetchSessionlessAppInfo, retrying on a safe network stack

Comment: Use this link for sending email without using intent .....
 [ Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a/2033124#2033124)

Comment: This is the linked that I used, and it worked great until recently.

Answer (score 0):

I fount the issue.

Turns out i took out the battery out of my phone and the certificate is somehow linked to the current time.

'at Jan 01 03:20:30 EET 2000' is not current time .. should of tipped me off.

Thanks anyways for your answers.